# Spring Integration DSL - How do I immediately start an asynchronous IntegrationFlow with DSL?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have an asynchronous IntegrationFlow that has some different behavior in different environments.  I deploy it in one environment & it will start immediately when I call it through a Gateway (this is desired behavior).  I deploy it in a different environment & the IntegrationFlow will not start until the top of every hour when a separate cron IntegrationFlow I have in the same project runs.  My question is how can I configure this IntegrationFlow to start immediately when it is called or manually invoke it so that it always runs immediately.  I'd really appreciate any help.  Here is my code:

The Gateway

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface SearchGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "searchFlow.input")
    void mySearch(FlowSearchDto flowSearchDto);

}
```

The IntegrationFlow

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Component
public class SearchEndpoint {

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    return Pollers.fixedDelay(1000).get();
}

@Bean(value = "searchFlow")
public IntegrationFlow searchFlow() {
  return IntegrationFlows
    .from("searchFlow.input")
    .split("payload.requestList", (Consumer) null)
    .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
    .enrichHeaders(new Consumer<HeaderEnricherSpec>() {

      @Override
      public void accept(HeaderEnricherSpec t) {
        t.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=utf8");
        t.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, "searchErrorChannel");
        t.headerExpression("restRequestDto", PAYLOAD);
        t.defaultOverwrite(true);
      }

    })
    .route("payload.serviceName", new Consumer<RouterSpec<String, ExpressionEvaluatingRouter>>() {

      @Override
      public void accept(RouterSpec<String, ExpressionEvaluatingRouter> spec) {
        spec.channelMapping(ServiceEndpointType.ABC.getServiceName(), "searchAbc")
            .channelMapping(ServiceEndpointType.DEF.getServiceName(), "searchDef")
            .channelMapping(ServiceEndpointType.GHI.getServiceName(), "searchGhi");
      }

    })
    .get();
}

@Bean(value = "searchAbcFlow")
public IntegrationFlow searchAbcFlow() {
return IntegrationFlows
    .from(MessageChannels.queue("searchAbc", 10))
    .enrichHeaders(new Consumer<HeaderEnricherSpec>() {

      @Override
      public void accept(HeaderEnricherSpec t) {
        t.header("url", searchAbcServiceUrl);
        t.defaultOverwrite(true);
      }

    })
    .handle(restClientHandler)
    .handle(message -> {})
    .get();
  }
}
```

Calling Service

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  @Override
  public boolean myIntegrationSearch(FlowSearchDto flowSearchDto) {

    // I NEED THIS CALL TO KICK OFF THE ASYNCHRONOUS FLOW IMMEDIATELY!!!
    searchGateway.mySearch(flowSearchDto);

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please, rephrase it somehow to make more understandable. You have a passive `IntegrationFlows.from("searchFlow.input")` which can be triggered only from some external call. I don't know how to help you since what you are showing doesn't fit the auto-start behavior.

Comment: What is `this flow` according your code? I see two of them in the snippet? Are you talking about `MessageChannels.queue("searchAbc", 10)`, which will block you until poller doesn't process those `10` enqueued messages. Well, still not clear what you want from us....

Comment: Hi thank you!  I'm calling this flow through the gateway with 'searchGateway.mySearch(flowSearchDto);' in MyServiceImpl.  I would expect the flow to execute immediately, but the flow isn't being invoked until much later (for some reason this flow will not run until the top of every hour).  The question I'm asking is how can I configure this flow so that it will run as soon as I call it through 'searchGateway.mySearch(flowSearchDto);'.  Does that make sense?

Comment: That second flow (searchAbcFlow) is called from the main flow (searchFlow) after a route().  This second (searchAbcFlow) flow should be immediately invoked from the searchFlow as well.

Comment: No, that doesn't. At least for me. You have there `.channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))` what means shifting to another thread from the caller's. Therefore the control returns to your `MyServiceImpl` pretty fast.

Comment: Well, try to remove that `10` from the queue channel definition and let it be unbounded.

Comment: Oh maybe that's what's going on.  I'll try and remove that .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadP‌​ool())) & also remove the 10 from the queue channel definition.  Are those the only things you see which might prevent the flow from executing immediately?  Do I need to set autoStartup to true or anything?

Comment: Well, as I said: it is performed immediately from the caller perspective. Only the concern that you have shifting to other threads and one of them may be definitely blocked because of queue size limit. That's maybe why you don't see the further process because your default poller is based on the cron